# Set the most significant bit

Tags: c++, c++17, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to toggle the most significant bit of an `unsigned int` based on a `bool` flag. This is my code for an hypothetical `K = unit64_t`:

### This is the `Item` class:

```
template<typename K>
class Item {
  public:
    K first;

    Item() = default;
    explicit Item(const K &elem, const bool flag = false) {
      first = elem & 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
      first |= (flag * 0x8000000000000000);
    }
};
```

Is there a way to do this fully generical? That it works for all kind of numeric `K`?

I tried with the `8 * sizeof(K)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `first`? What does your failed attempt using `sizeof` look like, and how is it not working?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm `first` is a class field of type `K`. I try to do this `first |= (flag * 8 * sizeof(K))`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have attempted. It is hard to understand exactly where each variable in your code came from.

Comment: @GaryNLOL I update the question adding all the `Item class`

Comment: Try Exclusive Or.  For a byte, performing `n ^ 0x80` will toggle the sign bit.

Comment: "Toggle" usually means "invert".  This looks more like you want to *set* the bit to the value of `flag`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option using only bit operations:

```
template<typename T>
void Item(T& elem, bool flag = false) {
    T mask = (T)1 << (sizeof(T) * 8 - 1);
    elem = (elem & ~mask) | (flag ? mask : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage `std::bitset` for this.  Not sure how well this optimizes, but it should optimize well and it will work generically and requires no bitwise operation knowledge.

```
template <typename T>
void toggle_msb(T& val)
{
    constexpr auto bit_width = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT;
    std::bitset<bit_width> temp(val);
    val = temp.flip(bit_width - 1).to_ullong();
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how do this with  bitwise operation?

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man See Lev M.'s answer

Comment: This flips the msb, but the code in OP's answer is more like a "set msb".

Answer (score 1):

Using bitwise operations, but without explicitly depending on the size of `T`:

```
template<typename T>
T set_top_bit(T value, bool state) {
    constexpr T mask = T(~T(0)) >> 1;
    value &= mask;
    if (state) value |= ~mask;
    return value;
}
```

`T(~T(0))` gets a `T` with all bits set<sup>1</sup>; `>> 1` throws out the bottom bit getting a 0 in from the top, so in `mask` we have a `T` with all bit set but the topmost. Notice that all this dance is purely formal—[this is all evaluated at compile time](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zn598sjzY).

The rest is pretty much like your code: mask out the top bit from `value` and OR it back in depending on `state` (`~mask` will be a `T` with only the top bit set).

---

1. Plain `~0` would result in an `int` set to -1, `~0U` in an `unsigned int` with all bits set; to obtain a `T` with all bits set, we need to flip the bits of a `T(0)` (so, a 0 of our T type), and also to cast back to `T` later, because, if `T` is smaller than `int`, `~T(0)` is actually equivalent to `~int(T(0))`, so `~0`, due to integer promotion rules.

Answer (score 0):

From this great post, [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit), you can use this branchless version:

```
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
constexpr T set_top_bit_v2(T value, bool state) {
    constexpr auto msb = (sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT) - 1;
    return (value & ~(T{1} << msb)) | (T{state} << msb);
}
```

Comparing the output with [the version of Matteo Italia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832011/3287591) on Godbolt ([here](https://godbolt.org/z/njqPM14aa)), despite the differences Clang seems to generate the same code, while GCC and MSVC seem to emit less instructions when using this version.